# Starfield Field of Nyx and Mirror March

Tags: magic-the-gathering

If you cast a [Mirror March](http://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Search/Default.aspx?name=%2b%5bMirror%20March%5d) and have five enchantments on the battlefield, including a [Starfield of Nyx](http://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Search/Default.aspx?name=%2b%5bStarfield%20of%20Nyx%5d) and another Mirror March, does the preexisting Mirror March copy the Mirror March that you just cast?

Comment: Is the second Starfield relevant to the question at all?

Comment: @ArcanistLupus Perhaps they mean "of the the five enchantments on the battlefield, there are two such that one is Mirror March and one is Starfield of Nyx".

Comment: Yes that is what I was trying to explain.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**When the Mirror March enters the battlefield, it copies itself and the existing Mirror March copies it.**

The Starfield's effect applies to the Mirror March as soon as it is on the battlefield, so each Mirror March sees both itself and any later Mirror March enter the battlefield as a creature, triggering its ability.

Comment: why would the first Mirror March copy itself? it's not entering the battlefield

Comment: I think that was a combination of misreading a previous comment and slightly misreading the question. I've fixed it.